# Google Maps v2 Set Zoom Level

Tags: android, zooming, google-maps-api-2

When I launch Google maps in Android, it shows the whole world. What do i need to change so as to set the zoom to the marker? Here are the codes. Thanks

```
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);


    LatLng cameraLatLng = sfLatLng;
    float cameraZoom = 17;


    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mapType = savedInstanceState.getInt("map_type", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        double savedLat = savedInstanceState.getDouble("lat");
        double savedLng = savedInstanceState.getDouble("lng");
        cameraLatLng = new LatLng(savedLat, savedLng);

        cameraZoom = savedInstanceState.getFloat("zoom", 30);

        googlemap.setMapType(mapType);
        googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cameraLatLng, cameraZoom));
```

Answer (score 48):

try this---->

```
  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)).setVisible(true);

  // Move the camera instantly to location with a zoom of 15.
  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15));

  // Zoom in, animating the camera.
  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);
```

Comment: Worked very well. Thanks alot

Comment: how to do the same (i.e setting zoom level) when using LatLngBounds?

Comment: @AllTimeKing-Narendra I don't know but a guy answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22553855/2388614). I hope this will help.

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to set the zoom so that the entire world would show? Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42329186/878126 ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#zoom), try to set zoom level to 1 which will show the world view.

Comment: @MrRoshanPawar I already tried. It doesn't show entire world. It barely even show continents.

Answer (score 6):

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(19));
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code may do the trick:

```
    function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);
```

You can try the following too:

```
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.setCenter(pt);
    map.setZoom(your desired zoom);
```

Edit:

```
 map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(xxxx,xxxx) , 14.0f) );//where 14.0 is the zoom level
```

Comment: Is set Position the Same as setCenter, if so ,i have already done that, but there is no property for setZoom...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Place (or bounds), you could zoom to it. E.g. zoom to specific country, city or address with **.newLatLngBounds()** method:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(place.getViewport(), 10)); // 10 is padding
```

Zoom level will be selected automatically. It works perfectly with location search.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;


   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(3.0f);
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(5.5f);
    }
```