# How set zoom level on google map dynamically in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Facing a problem to set dynamic zoom level in android google map.

something like doing In map application (system application of android).!

[image: Searched City (zoom level for city)]

[image: Searched Area of city (zoom level for area)]

I used below method of map

mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(START_POINT, 50));
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0f));

Comment: mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(START_POINT, 50));
   mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0f));

Comment: there is a magical button called **edit** below your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use following code:

```
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17),200, null);
```

Here 17 is zoom level you can change that.

Or try following code to cover all points

```
//Calculate the markers to get their position
LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (Marker m : markers) {
    b.include(m.getPosition());
}
LatLngBounds bounds = b.build();
//Change the padding as per needed
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 25,25,5);
mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Comment: thanks for comment, but will be static for all search result, I would like to make like google map application available in-build app, different zoom level for search criteria. i.e. city, area or state

Comment: thanks man, can you please brifly explain below line CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 25,25,5);

Comment: There you go .. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds, int)